# Rails3 namespace sharing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, namespaces

I want to divide my app in two namespaces, Cms and Front. Based on that I will have for example scaffold in Front named User which will handle users data of those who register in service. But the thing is, that in Cms I would also like to have acces and be able to manage users like block action, delete, resend invitation, send email etc. .

What would be the best solution for that. Should I make two separate scaffolds one in Cms another in Front and handle with them the same table in DB or should I create some Module to handle common actions for both namespaces ? Of course for each namespace I will have different DB prefix, how to work it around ?

Answer (score 0):

just don't add a namespace for the common stuff. or you could also add a Common namespace to them.